# ¿Como Llenar textbox según elección de DropDownList?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms

Al seleccionar un valor del dropdownlist que son nombres de productos quiero que automáticamente se llene el textbox con el precio de dicho producto, se que es con el evento SelectedIndexChanged pero no encuentro como codificarlo.
Asi lleno los DDL:

```
public DataSet Consultar(string strSQL)
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cn);
        SqlDataAdapter das = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        das.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();
        return ds;
    }

 private void InicialProductos()
    {
        ddlProducto.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM productos");
        ddlProducto.DataTextField = "descripcion";
        ddlProducto.DataValueField = "id";
        ddlProducto.DataBind();
        ddlProducto.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));


    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si necesitan algo mas diganme

Encontre este ejemplo pero no logo que me de:

```
 protected void ddlProducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select preciodolar from productos where id =@id", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlProducto.SelectedValue;
        SqlDataAdapter dr;
        cn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection());
        while(dr.Read)
        {
            txtPrecio.Text = dr.item("preciodolar").ToString();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Solo has puesto el codigo que llena lo que me imagino es el combobox, pon tambien el codigo del metodo del evento. Pero intentare responder igual, supongo que en los argumentos del metodo del evento que mencionas recibes informacion de la seleccion, supongo a partir de ahi puedes obtener el elemento seleccionado, y de ahi sus propiedades como el precio, en ese mismo metodo asignas el precio a tu text box. Pero porfavor pon mas informacion de tu configuracion y codigo.

Comment: No se como comenzar el metodo en el evento pero encontre un ejemplo pero no me funciona lo agregare para que te des una idea de lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 0):

Voy a suponeru que tu escenario es de la siguiente manera

Estos serian tus controles

```
 <div>
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="lista" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lista_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="descripcion" DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="texto"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

en el page load podrias cargar la informacion necesaria para los dropdowns. Para acortar la respuesta digamos que es un metodo que ya tienes anteriormente.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MetodoParaCargarDropDown();
}
```

En el SelectedIndexChanged tienes que ir a la DB hacer la consulta, obtener el valor y asignarlo a tu TextBox.Text. Puedes hacerlos de esta manera.

```
 protected void lista_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   using (var conn = new SqlConnection("MiConnectionString"))
   {
     var cmd = new SqlCommand("select preciodolar from productos where id =@id", conn);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lista.SelectedValue);
     cmd.Connection = conn;
     conn.Open();

     using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
       var itemId = "";
       while (reader.Read())
       {
         itemId = reader[0].ToString();
       }
     }

     conn.Close();
     texto.Text = itemId;
   }
 }
```